# How can I download large file from CloudFront using HTTP range Concurrently

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am attempting to use a CloudFront URL to download a large file, ranging between 100-250GB, employing the HTTP Range method. My goal is to concurrently fetch data while ensuring that the data is sequentially written to a single file without losing any bytes. To achieve this, I am utilizing the stream package from [https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sourcegraph/conc@v0.3.0/stream#example-Stream](https://stackoverflow.com).

The provided code snippet demonstrates the implementation, where I spawn goroutines for concurrent data retrieval and sequential writing to a file. However, when comparing the execution time with a single HTTP request, the difference is minimal, with just a few minutes of variation. I am seeking suggestions on reducing the download time further. Specifically, I am interested in exploring whether there is a method to write data in parallel to a single file while maintaining the correct order, or if there are alternative approaches that could be implemented to optimize the download process. Any insights or recommendations to expedite the download process would be greatly appreciated.

```
func ParallelDownloader(numWorkers int, Destination string, seqRangingClient http.Client, rangeslice []ByteRange, url string) error {
    streamer := stream.New().WithMaxGoroutines(numWorkers)
    
    file, err := os.Create(Destination)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fmt.Printf("File '%s' created successfully in the current directory.\n", Destination)

    for _, byteRange := range rangeslice {
        streamer.Go(func() stream.Callback {
            data:=downloadPart(&seqRangingClient, url, byteRange)
            fmt.Println("goroutine started")
            return func() {
                
                _, err := file.Seek(0, io.SeekEnd)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Error seeking in file: %v\n", err)
                    return 
                }

                _, err = file.Write(data)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Error writing to file: %v\n", err)
                    return
                }
            }
        })
    }
    streamer.Wait()
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Concurrency makes more efficient use of CPU cycles, which are not the bottleneck for downloading a file. Network and disk IO performance are the bottlenecks, and there's nothing concurrency can do about either.

Comment: Create a sparse file of the appropriate size and then open it in every goroutine and write to the correct offset.  It's probably not going to make the overall process go faster, but it will improve behavior of retries.